# How to get width of an image after setting the height

Tags: jquery, html, css, width

I have set the height of my images to 100px (in css).
The width is automated to keep the images in proportion but how do I get the width with jquery/js if I haven't specifically set it my self?

This is what I have tryed:

```
1) $(this).width();

2) $(this).css("width");
```

Both not working, any ideas?

Comment: Both should work, what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Please provide your code in a jsFiddle or something similar. As it is we are unable to help you because both methods should work

Comment: var x = 0;
                $("img").each(function () {
                    x += $(this).width();
                }
                );
                alert(x);     //////x is printing as 0

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KFhG8/

Comment: I was using document ready instead of on load, so it was showing 0 before the pictures were populated, I guess that was my problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
var x = 0;
$("img").each(function () {
x += $(this).width();
});
    alert(x);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFhG8/

Comment: Yeah I was getting the width of the images using $(document).ready before the images had been loaded on screen. Document.on(load) is correct thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use clientWidth for that

```
var width=document.getElementById('imageid').clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use maths and calculate it if you are struggling.

```
mynewwidth =  ( $(this).width() /  $(this).height() ) * mynewheight;
```

But it should work anyway see my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/davidja/KFhG8/4/

```
$(window).on('load', function () {


    mynewheight = 50;
    $("img").height(mynewheight);   

    // via $("img").width()
    alert( $("img").width());

    // maths
    alert(( $("img").width() /  $("img").height() ) * mynewheight)
});
```